# What is the difference between these two method calls in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, callback

First time I Wrote this code and did not work it gives me error http is not defined.

```
importFile(fileId: string, fileName: string): void {
    this.fileService.importFileById(fileId, fileName, this.refreshFiles);
}
```

Second time I Wrote this code and did work but I don't understand what is the difference.

```
importFile(fileId: string, fileName: string): void {
    this.fileService.importFileById(fileId, fileName, () => {
        this.refreshFiles();
    });
}
```

The code from refreshFiles() is like that:

```
refreshFiles(): void {
    this.http.get('api/Files/GetFiles').subscribe(result => {
        //etc
    }, error => console.error(error));
}
```

What is the difference between these two pieces of code?
Why first code did not work and the second works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between `this.refreshFiles` and `this.refreshFiles()` is that the first one returns you a reference to a function without a context (you need to provide your `this` when you will call this function) whilst the second one calls the function directly and provides `this` implicitly.

What you can do: you can use `this.refreshFiles.bind(this)` to explicitly set the context of the function returned by `this.refreshFiles` and pass it as is.

```
this.fileService.importFileById(fileId, fileName, this.refreshFiles.bind(this));
```

The arrow function that you use in your working example is very similar to `bind` (in fact arrow function is a syntactical sugar for `bind`).

Another example:

```
const test = {
  run() {
    console.log(typeof this.run)
  }
}

console.log(test.run()) // function, because we call it as test.run() and provide test as `this`

let testrun = test.run;

console.log(testrun()) // undefined, because testrun has no `this`

testrun = test.run.bind(test);

console.log(testrun()) // function, because testrun has a bound `this`
```

Comment: Got it! this.refreshFiles - it's a pointer to the function and this.refreshFiles() - it's a function call in a given context.